# Ошибка в коде, игра на android

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Пишу игру на unity используя c# под android. Суть кода такова: Объект вращается с постоянной скоростью, но если сделать удерживающее касание (скрипт работает только тогда, когда палец касается экрана), вращение объекта должно замедлиться, но вместо этого он просто перестает вращаться... вот код:

```
public class TouchRotate : MonoBehaviour {

public float velocity=180;
public float slow_velocity=90;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            // замедление вращения при длительном касании экрана
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, slow_velocity * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, velocity * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде есть такая ветка в условиях, в которой ничего не выполняется. А конкретно - если `Input.touchCount > 0`, но `touch.phase != TouchPhase.Began`.

Если вы хотите сделать то, что задумали, то вам необходимо хранить какой-то флаг. При `touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began` выставляете его в `true`, при `touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended` в  `false`. А в вашем условии проверяете именно этот флаг.

Потому что оба ивента срабатывают лишь единожды, а проверку вы делаете в каждом кадре.

Кстати, вместо флага можно просто проверять на то, что состояние либо `Stationary`, либо `Moved`. Но это уж как вам больше нравится. Справка [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html)